# Use Object class in Java?

Tags: java

I read in a Java book that all classes in Java extend a class Object.
What is use of `Object` class and why all classes extend it? Can anyone help me understand that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java guys were smart enough to implement the language make it eachier for program, `Object` class is extended by all classes and benifits are :

- Giving some basic functionalities by default to all the classes. (such as **toString, equals, hashcode, thread wait and notify** functionality)
- Any type of object can be passed around as an arbitrary `Object` class object.(**Generic** collections have used it like hell.)

There may be some other uses, which I may not be aware of. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just inheritance theory applies here too.

> Every class you use or write inherits the instance methods of Object.

So common methods that every **actual Object** must support are separated and defined in `Object` class.

**Note** that there is default implementation for methods in Object ,So that you will not end up in writing basic functionality of your each `class`.

Well written docs explained , what  are those methods and why. Checkout here once [Object as a Superclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html)

Answer (score 1):

It has three broad advantages:

1. **synchronization** (wait, notify, notifyAll).
2. **garbage collection callback**  (finalize)
3. **collection support**  (hashCode, equals)

To learn more, go to this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html).